# Classification of compact smooth manifolds of dimension 3.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I know classification of compact dimension 2 smooth manifolds. They are diffeomorphic to a sphere with n "ears" (connected sum of n tori) or a sphere with m mobius strips (connected sum of m real projective planes).
I know only that geometric hypothesis proved by Perelman says something about 3 manifolds, but I can't find similar as above precise classification for compact smooth manifolds of dimension 2. Is there a similarsimple classification? IF Yes, could You leave a link to it or write it in comment?

Comment: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/3-manifolds#Classification.2FCharacterization

Answer (score 3):

A manifold is called *prime* if whenever it is homeomorphic to a connected sum, one of the two summands is homeomorphic to a sphere.

In dimension two, the closed prime manifolds are $S^2$, $\mathbb{RP}^2$, and $S^1\times S^1$. By the classification of surfaces, every closed two-dimensional manifold is homeomorphic to a connected sum of prime manifolds. In the orientable case, the connected summands are unique up to $S^2$ summands (you can always connected sum with $S^2$ without changing anything). In the non-orientable case, we no longer have uniqueness as $(S^1\times S^1)\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$. However, one can recover uniqueness (up to spherical summands) if one prohibits the use of $S^1\times S^1$ summands.

There is a similar story for closed three-manifolds. The prime decomposition theorem for three-manifolds states that every closed three-manifold is homeomorphic to a connected sum of prime manifolds. If the orientable case, the connected summands are unique up to $S^3$ summands. If $M$ is non-orientable, then uniqueness no longer holds, however one can recover uniqueness by prohibiting the use of $S^2\times S^1$ as one of the connected summands.

The key difference between dimensions two and three is that there are infinitely many prime three-manifolds.  In the orientable case, they fit into three categories:

1. those manifolds covered by $S^3$,
2. the manifold $S^2\times S^1$, and
3. orientable aspherical manifolds.

These categories can also be characterised via the fundamental group: namely finite, infinite cyclic, and infinite non-cyclic respectively.

In the non-orientable case however, there are too many prime manifolds to admit a classification; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3750406/39599) of mine.

In dimension four, we no longer have uniqueness, even in the orientable case. For example, $(S^2\times S^2)\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$. Note the similarity to the fact that $(S^1\times S^1)\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: +1. I always enjoy classic differential topology problems. What is the advantage of being unique?

Comment: @C.F.G: Questions about manifolds can sometimes be translated into questions about their prime summands. If the decomposition is not unique, then the answer may depend on *how* we write our manifold as a connected sum of prime manifolds.